# generic type interface cast to a specific interface

Tags: c#, .net

How can you cast an interface with a generic type to a common interface?

Lets say we have the following interfaces/objects:

```
public interface IAction : IAction<object> { }
public interface IAction<T>
{
    T PerformAction();
}
public class SomeAction : IAction<string>
{
    public string PerformAction()
    {
        return "some action result value";
    }
}
public class OtherAction : IAction<int>
{
    public int PerformAction()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Then if we try to code it in a console application:

```
List<IAction> actions = new List<IAction>();
actions.Add(new SomeAction());
actions.Add(new OtherAction());
actions.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.PerformAction()));
```

How can we work around the error "cannot convert from 'SomeAction' to 'IAction'"?

Comment: You don't.  Those objects don't implement `IAction`.  If you want to put them in a list of `IAction`, they'll need to actually implement that interface (or convert them into an object that does, as the error message indicates).

Comment: Look into Duck Typing if you are dead set on it. The dynamic keyword allows for it and there is a Nuget library for it too which achieves it by reflection, I forget its name. To be honest though, you probably just need to rethink your design.

Comment: @James `dynamic` allows for dynamic typing (hence the name).  It doesn't allow for duck typing, which is done statically, not dynamically (but implicitly, rather than implicitly).

Comment: Write separate `IAction` and `IAction<T>` interfaces, and have the concrete classes implement both, with the non-generic one implemented explicitly so the like-named/diferently-typed members don't collide. This is how `List<T>` implements both `IList` and `IList<T>`: The non-generic indexer is explicit. Or derive the generic interface from the non-generic use `new` as Igor suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inheritance hierarchy does not make sense, you should have `IAction<T>` extend `IAction` and not the other way around.

You also need to add any common methods you want to call to `IAction` and, if the methods have the same name and parameters, implement them using an explicit interface implementation. It is on the common interface implementation you will be calling the method.

```
public interface IAction
{
    object PerformAction();
}
public interface IAction<T> : IAction
{
    new T PerformAction();
}
public class SomeAction : IAction<string>
{
    object IAction.PerformAction()
    {
        return PerformAction();
    }

    public string PerformAction()
    {
        return "some action result value";
    }
}
public class OtherAction : IAction<int>
{
    object IAction.PerformAction()
    {
        return PerformAction();
    }
    public int PerformAction()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Calling code

```
List<IAction> actions = new List<IAction>();
actions.Add(new SomeAction());
actions.Add(new OtherAction());
actions.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.PerformAction()));
```

Comment: This is perfect! For the life of me, I couldn't see that I had it backwards! thanks so much :)